# How do I use Sqlite.Net Extensions Filter

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, sqlite.net

I am using the [Sqlite.Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) library to get objects from my database.

I have a list of `Id's` and I would like to get all the objects from the database where my list contains that Id.

I have got the following:

```
var filteredCalls = listOfIds;            
var conn = Databsae.Connection;
var NewCalls = conn.GetAllWithChildren<Call>(x => filteredCalls.Any(y => y == x.Id));
```

But this code returns the error:

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotSupportedException:
>   Cannot compile: Lambda 08-30 15:46:57.210 E/mono-rt (16849):   at
>   SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x007aa] in :0  08-30 15:46:57.210 E/mono-rt (16849):   at
>   SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x001a5] in :0  08-30 15:46:57.210 E/mono-rt (16849):   at
>   SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].GenerateCommand (System.String
>   selectionList) [0x0006d] in <filename unknown>:0  08-30 15:46:57.210
>   E/mono-rt (16849):   at SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].GetEnumerator ()
>   [0x00008] in :0  08-30 15:46:57.210 E/mono-rt
>   (16849):   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor
>   (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00073] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs:98
>   08-30 15:46:57.210 E/mono-rt (16849):   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source)
>   [0x00011] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:835
>   08-30 15:46:57.210 E/mono-rt (16849):   at
>   SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.ReadOperations.GetAllWithChildren[T]
>   (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 filter, Boolean recursive)
>   [0x00015] in
>   /Users/redent/Documents/workspace/sqlite-net-extensions/SQLiteNetExtensions/Extensions/ReadOperations.cs:60

So how am I supposed to use the `GetAllWithChildren` method without it crashing? The documentation is quite sparse

**Extra**

This is the [line where the method is implemented](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/b6d604604da1bda30d5558540617d4179bac73a1/SQLiteNetExtensions/Extensions/ReadOperations.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#ReadOperations.cs-54)

Possibly lambda expressions are not supported in Sqlite as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21976381/2987066) if this is the case, what is the alternative / how was this method supposed to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looked like `Sqlite.Net` could not cope with the Lambda expression nested within another lamdba expression. I therefore changed my filter to be:

```
var NewCalls = conn.GetAllWithChildren<DiaryCall>(x => filteredCalls.Contains(x.Id));
```

Comment: Seems that this "Too many SQL variables" happens, when the `filteredCalls` list has more than 999 elements (the default max. parameters value), [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33831384/107625).